# codeigniter template system

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter

Hello all i have download a template system but i cant get it to work, i got this error
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/ocular_helper.php

The name of the template is: ocular

My project can you see here https://github.com/SimonJ/Hip-hop-project

hope some one can help me what im doing wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, given the error you're receiving, you are clearly missing a file called `ocular_helper.php` which Ocular expects to be in `/application/helpers/`.

Are you using the [latest version](https://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library) of the Ocular library? As you can [see here](https://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library/wiki/Installation), it looks like the latest version doesn't use any helpers.

Comment: i have done so it dont autoload ocular helper, and now i got this error An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: ocular

Comment: @ole: Based on that error, I would assume that the Ocular library is not being loaded. I'd recommend downloading the latest version (linked to in my answer above), and follow the installation and configuration instructions here: https://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library/wiki/